# open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) ANDROID 11

Tags: android, kotlin, storage, scoped-storage

I'm converting a base64 file to a pdf, so first i'm converting from base64 to an array of bytes and then I write it on a FileOutputStream. My problem is when I try to store it adn then open it with pdf viewer i get this error:

```
 Faild to generate pdf from base64: /storage/emulated/0/Download/conclusions.pdf: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Also I'm giving it the necesarry permissions to work, as I use a File provider because the app works on android 11. Here is the code I use:

Activity:

```
private fun generatePDFFromBase64(base64: String?, fileName: String?) {
        try {
            val decodedBytes: ByteArray = Base64.decode(base64, Base64.DEFAULT)
            val fos = FileOutputStream(fileName?.let { getFilePath(it) })
            fos.write(decodedBytes)
            fos.flush()
            fos.close()

            fileName?.let { openDownloadedPDF(it) }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.e("TAG", "Faild to generate pdf from base64: ${e.localizedMessage}")
        }
    }

    private fun openDownloadedPDF(fileName: String) {
        val file = File(getFilePath(fileName))


        if (file.exists()) {

            val path: Uri = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                FileProvider.getUriForFile(requireContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file)
            } else {
                Uri.fromFile(file)
            }

            generalFile = file
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf")
            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
            val chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open with")
            try {
                startActivity(chooserIntent)
            } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                Log.e("TAG", "Failed to open PDF  ${e.localizedMessage}")
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getFilePath(filename: String): String {
        val file =
            File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).path)
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs()
        }
        return file.absolutePath.toString() + "/" + filename + ".pdf"
    }
```

Android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:name="university"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="${appIcon}"
        android:roundIcon="${appIconRound}"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.University"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            tools:replace="android:authorities">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths"
                tools:replace="android:resource" />
        </provider>
```

filepaths:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="external"
        path="." />
    <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <cache-path
        name="cache"
        path="." />
    <external-cache-path
        name="external_cache"
        path="." />
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

Comment: `My problem is when I try to store it adn then open it with pdf viewer` Or it is while saving. Or it is while opening. Please be exact. When?

Answer (score 0):

open your app info an app permission click all permissions after show all permission click to enable after problem resolved.